# Dart: How do you remove parts of a list if they exist in another list?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var listA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var listB = ['a', 'b']
```

How do I return a list where it contains all elements of `listA` that don't exist in `listB`? Meaning, how do I return the following:

```
var listC = ['c', 'd']
```

Comment: I would suggest using sets for this instead of lists if possible. Set has a `difference` method built in which has this behavior. So you can do `var setC = setA.difference(setB);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` the `b list` and remove each item of it from `a list`, Try this:

```
listB.map((e) => listA.remove(e)).toList();
print("listA = $listA") //['c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listB.length; i++) {
  listA.remove(listB[i]);
  listC = listA;
}
```